# Runtime error 1004 when trying to resize

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet where employees enter a reservation on each row in Excel. I'm trying to create code that will prevent them from skipping rows.

I have a formula in Col W that determines how many cells were filled out in a particular row (Col C:K) so that the row has at least most the info needed. I have a worksheet change event within that sheet that when the formula reaches 6, the code should unlock the next row of Col C:K, allowing the user to use the next row. My code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range

Set rng = Range("W6:W504")
For Each c In rng
    If c.Value >= 6 Then
        Worksheets("January").Unprotect Password:="XXX"
        c.Offset(1, -20).Resize(0, 8).Locked = False       'should unlock C7:K7
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

I've tried to combine the offset and resize lines, enter them on separate lines, select them then apply the unlock, but all to no avail. The closest I've come is to separate the offset and resize, and select the appropriate cell on the next row (C7), but I can't get it to resize then apply the lock. Thanks!

Comment: You can't Resize zero rows, should be either `Resize(1, 8)` or just `Resize(, 8)`.

Comment: Beyond the zero rows issue, C:K is 9 columns, not 8. Resize is inclusive, Offset is not.

Comment: @sjr Ah! I remember reading somewhere that you could omit the row number but thought it said for good practice that you should still fill in a value. I'm guessing you can't do the 0 because that would tell it that it doesn't exist? Anywho, thanks for the help. Don't think I would have figured that out.